# How to add dependency to non gradle project using gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have gradle project and I would like to add dependency to project which does not use build tools like gradle or maven.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
commonfolder\
    gradleProject\
        build.gradle
    nonGradleProject\
```

In IntelliJ I added nonGradleProject as module and I can import classes in gradleProject but gradle during compileJava step does not see these classes.

I tried add

```
include ':nonGradleProject'
```

in settings.gradle and

```
implementation project(":nonGradleProject")
```

in build.gradle but it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will answer on my own question :)

I did it in 2 ways:

First: I added gradle to nonGradleProject and

```
include ':nonGradleProject'
project(':nonGradleProject').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../nonGradleProject')
```

to settings.gradle and

```
implementation project(":nonGradleProject")
```

to build.gradle

Second: I changed structure and added nonGradleProject to GradleProject

```
commonfolder\
    gradleProject\
        build.gradle
        nonGradleProject\
```

and added

```
include ':nonGradleProject'
```

to settings.gradle and

```
implementation project(":nonGradleProject")
```

to build.gradle